# update pivot table with multiple ids

Tags: mysql, laravel, pivot-table, multiple-columns

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
```

this is what we use while update a pivot table . but I have two same values as `$roleId` in my table. I want to update only one of them. how can we do that?

For example; this is my sql table

```
userId -- roleId -- attributeId
  1          1          1
  1          1          2
```

this is another pivot table that explains better:

```
order_id --- product_id --- feature_id --- product_quantity
```

in an order I have multiple products.
Any products can have multiple features.
I am trying to save database the same product with different features in an order, and the problem begins here, it doesn't work with this commands:

```
$order = Order::create( $request->all());
      $product_list = $request->input('product_list');
      $feature_list = $request->input('feature_list');
      $product_quantity = $request->input('product_quantity');

       /* attach pivot table */
      $order->product()->attach($product_list);  

      /* get the product list as array */              
      foreach($product_list as $key => $product_id)
      {   
        $order->product()->updateExistingPivot($product_id, array(
                        'feature_id' => $feature_list[$key],
                        'product_quantity' => $product_quantity[$key], // product_quantity is array
                        ));
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled the problem by this way **and it works**... If you can find another solution, please share here...
In my store function;

```
 public function store(OrderRequest $request)
    {
      $order = Order::create( $request->all());
      $product_row = $request->input('product_row'); 
      $product_list = $request->input('product_list');
      $feature_list = $request->input('feature_list');
      $product_quantity = $request->input('product_quantity');
      $product_status = $request->input('product_status' );

       /* attach pivot table */
       foreach($product_row as $key=>$value){

      $order->product()->attach($product_list[$key], ['feature_id'=>$feature_list[$key], 'product_quantity'=>$product_quantity[$key], 'product_status'=>$product_status[$key]] );

        }
}
```

and update function:

```
public function update(Order $order, OrderRequest $request) 
    {
      $order->update($request->all());

      $product_row = $request->input('product_row');
      $product_list = $request->input('product_list'); 
      $feature_list = $request->input('feature_list');
      $product_quantity = $request->input('product_quantity');
      $product_status = $request->input('product_status' );
      /* clear pivot table for the current order */
      $order->product()->detach();
      /* attach pivot table */
       foreach($product_row as $key=>$value){

      $order->product()->attach($product_list[$key], ['feature_id'=>$feature_list[$key], 'product_quantity'=>$product_quantity[$key], 'product_status'=>$product_status[$key]] );

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This to update mapping table.

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
            if(empty($user->id) === false)
            {
                $user->roles()->detach();
                $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);
                return redirect()->route('users')->with('success', 'User has been updated successfully');
            }

      return redirect()->route('users')->with('error', 'Unable to update User. Please try again later');
```

Comment: I added a detailed example. it can explain the problem better

Comment: Can you divide that  into two tables.   order_id --- product_id  & product_id --- feature_id with both belongsToMany relationship

Comment: I can explain you it with scenario. The users have multiple roles and each roles have multiple permissions. so user--roles in one table and roles--permission in another table

Comment: I can't divide into two tables, because each orders can include the same product and each product can include different quantities. So, order-product-feature and quantity should be in the same pivot table.